# Run multiple Colab Notebooks from same directory

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I have 4 Colab Notebooks, each running different scripts.
Also, I created a main.ipynb where I want to call these scripts with as result only have the output of the other 4 scripts.

In Jupyter Notebook there is this function called `%run` to process other notebooks.
When I run this command only the json output of the .ipynb notebook file is executed, but my goal is to run the script in that notebook.

How can I run scripts from other Colab Notebooks, the same as the 'run' function in Jupiter Notebook?
All scripts I want to run are in the same Google Drive folder as the 'main' notebook who met execute these files.

[image]